# ComboBox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I have a combobox with multi selection. when i click on add button, which ever data is selected in the Combobox, those data has to be displayed in the another comboBox.

Please check the code and Can anyone of you please help me on this.

```
<mx:HBox>
 <mx:Label width="140" text="{resourceManager.getString   ('resources', 'settings_configuration_database_select_object_instance')}"/>
     <mx:List id="obj_instance" enabled="true" allowMultipleSelection="true" width="164" height="70"/>      
     <mx:Spacer width="20"/>
     <mx:Button label=">>"/>
     <mx:List id="selected_instance" enabled="true" allowMultipleSelection="true" width="164" height="70"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
<ov:HPButton label=">>">
    <ov:click><![CDATA[
        for each (var item:* in obj_instance.selectedItems)
            selected_instance.dataProvider.addItem(item);
    ]]></ov:click>
</ov:HPButton>
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure that the `dataProvider` of `instance` is something reasonable (like an `ArrayCollection`)…

Comment: What did you modify? And have you tried my suggestion? If not, please modify it as appropriate then try it.

Comment: I had tried your suggestion. It was workin fine.
Thanks David